# ¿Cómo sustituir una variable dentro de un hash en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

**En un javascript tengo las siguientes variables:**

```
var num_a = 7;
var num_b = 5;
```

y quiero sustituir los numeros por variables

```
var datos = [{ name: "Pedacito", data: [["Muestra A", 7], ["Muestra B", 5]]}]
```

**He probado todo esto y ninguno me camina:**

**OPCION 1**

```
var datos = [{ name: "Pedacito", data: [["Muestra A", $(num_a)], ["Muestra B",$(num_b)]]}]
```

**OPCION 2**

```
var datos = [{ name: "Pedacito", data: [["Muestra A", $(#num_a)], ["Muestra B",$(#num_a)]]}]
```

**OPCION 3**

```
var datos = [{ name: "Pedacito", data: [["Muestra A", $(num_a)], ["Muestra B",$(num_a)]]}]
```

**OPCION 4**

```
var datos = [{ name: "Pedacito", data: [["Muestra A", ${num_a}], ["Muestra B",${num_a}]]}]
```

***¿Alguna idea como puedo hacer?***

Comment: Cual es  el resultado que  quieres obtener, aun no se entiende bien la pregunta

Comment: Como lo has editado ahora sí funciona. ¿Revisaste la respuesta de @VickMuñoz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sólo tienes que agregar la variable, te falta una **,** en `"Muestra A",`, arrojaba un error.

```js
var num_a = 7;
var num_b = 5;


var datos = [{ name: "Pedacito", data: [["Muestra A", num_a], ["Muestra B", num_b]]}];

console.log(datos);
```

Comment: Correcto. Dentro de `data` habría varios sub-arrays y en uno de ellos faltaba la coma. Bien visto +1.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano **:D**

Comment: Estás modificando la variable datos? Porque si haces `console.log(typeof datos[0].data[0][1]);` el tipo de dato es `number`.